# Module Not Found Error for '@hotwired/stimulus-loading' in Webpack Dev Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webpacker, stimulusjs, hotwire

I'm encountering an error when running the bin/webpack-dev-server command in my project. The error message states 'Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hotwired/stimulus-loading' in [path/to/project]'. I have checked my project configuration and the required package seems to be installed. How can I resolve this issue and successfully run the webpack-dev-server?

```
/hammurabi# bin/webpack-dev-server
warning package.json: No license field
ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://localhost:3035/
ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from /packs/
ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /hammurabi/public/packs
ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /index.html
✖ ｢wdm｣: Hash: f5f8f2930950bf50c483
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 704ms
Built at: 06/12/2023 11:28:21 PM
                                       Asset        Size         Chunks                         Chunk Names
      js/application-48f396e01e11579d2852.js     435 KiB    application  [emitted] [immutable]  application
  js/application-48f396e01e11579d2852.js.map     485 KiB    application  [emitted] [dev]        application
              js/gpt-a0aba0ad11fbb99c6400.js     354 KiB            gpt  [emitted] [immutable]  gpt
          js/gpt-a0aba0ad11fbb99c6400.js.map     393 KiB            gpt  [emitted] [dev]        gpt
    js/quick-website-b25ea13a20e82a47498a.js     402 KiB  quick-website  [emitted] [immutable]  quick-website
js/quick-website-b25ea13a20e82a47498a.js.map     455 KiB  quick-website  [emitted] [dev]        quick-website
                               manifest.json  1000 bytes                 [emitted]

ERROR in ./app/javascript/controllers/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hotwired/stimulus-loading' in '/hammurabi/app/javascript/controllers'
resolve '@hotwired/stimulus-loading' in '/hammurabi/app/javascript/controllers'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/controllers)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/app/javascript
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
      /hammurabi/app/javascript/controllers/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /hammurabi/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /hammurabi/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/node_modules
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading doesn't exist
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/controllers/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/app/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.mjs]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.js]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.sass]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.scss]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.css]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.module.css]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.png]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.svg]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.gif]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/stimulus-loading.jpg]

ERROR in ./app/javascript/packs/application.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@hotwired/turbo-rails' in '/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs'
resolve '@hotwired/turbo-rails' in '/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
    resolve as module
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/app/javascript
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
      /hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /hammurabi/app/javascript/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /hammurabi/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
      looking for modules in /hammurabi/node_modules
        using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules)
          Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
          using description file: /hammurabi/package.json (relative path: ./node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails)
            no extension
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
            .mjs
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs doesn't exist
            .js
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js doesn't exist
            .sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass doesn't exist
            .scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss doesn't exist
            .css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css doesn't exist
            .module.sass
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass doesn't exist
            .module.scss
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss doesn't exist
            .module.css
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css doesn't exist
            .png
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png doesn't exist
            .svg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg doesn't exist
            .gif
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif doesn't exist
            .jpeg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg doesn't exist
            .jpg
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg doesn't exist
            as directory
              /hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails doesn't exist
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/packs/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/app/javascript/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/app/node_modules]
[/node_modules]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.mjs]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.js]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.sass]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.scss]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.css]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.sass]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.scss]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.module.css]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.png]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.svg]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.gif]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpeg]
[/hammurabi/node_modules/@hotwired/turbo-rails.jpg]
```